# Apache Pig Distinct and Count

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to figure out the following question.

How many female users provided at least one rating of 4.  I think my join and filters are correct but I cant figure out the distinct count part  Have tried numerous versions of the below.

```
a = load '/user/pig/movie' AS (userid:int, movieid:int, rating:int, timestamp:chararray);
b = load '/user/pig/reviewer' using PigStorage('|') AS (userid:int, age:int, gender:chararray, occupation:chararray, zip:chararray);
a1 = filter a by rating == 4;
b1 = filter b by gender == 'F';
c = join a1 by userid, b1 by userid;
d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(DISTINCT(userid));
dump d;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that and I'm getting an error - could not resolve DISTINCT using imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to GROUP before COUNT.Ref:[COUNT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#count) requires a preceding GROUP ALL statement for global counts and a GROUP BY statement for group counts.

```
d = GROUP c BY userid;
e = FOREACH d GENERATE COUNT(DISTINCT(b1.userid));
dump e;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I had to group by rating not userid and it worked.